# When citing from a foreign language and including a translation - what is correct?

Tags: citations, citation-style, quotation

Which version is correct (using APA7)?:

- "Die Sonne ist hell. [The sun is bright]" (Müller, 2010, S. 1)
- "Die Sonne ist hell." [The sun is bright] (Müller, 2010, S. 1)

So - brackets inside of the quotation marks or afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

The way in which you have ask your question indicates that you are interested in the form of the in-text citation rather than in the form of the reference in the bibliography. However, I think you have got the style wrong.

My understanding is that the translated title should ***not*** be indicated in the body of the text; it should appear only in the bibliography/reference section. The in-text citation, on the assumption that you want to mention the title of the book in the body of your paper, should read:

> "Die Sonne is hell" (Müller, 2010, p. 1)

Note also that I have changed *Seite* 1 to *page* 1 because for this question about referencing to make sense in the form you have given, you must surely be asking about publishing in an English language journal.

The referencing in the bibliography would include the translated title, have no quotation marks unless a journal-specific style required it, and would appear as:

> Müller, J. (2010). Die Sonne ist hell [The sun is bright]. Place of publication: Publisher.

**Correction and additional information**: @Andreas_Blass, in his comment, makes the observation that it is more likely you are asking about simply including a foreign language quotation (reading "Die Sonne ist hell") in your text, than citing a work called "Die Sonne ist hell". In that case, as mentioned [here](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/translations/) (and the same in APA 7th edition), the quotation marks should appear only around the foreign language part. So,

> "Die Sonne ist hell" [The sun is bright] (Müller, 2010, p. 1).

Note that you will still want to have page 1, rather than Seite 1.

Comment: Is it obvious that "Die Sonne ist hell" is the title of the cited work? I assumed it was just information provided in the body of the work.

Comment: You are quite possible correct. Thank you. I have added to the answer.